# Android dev: PhoneLookup._ID, Phone.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID all the same?

Tags: android, contacts

Do they all refer to the same unique contactId of a contact person?

Answer (score 2):

They should, but it's not guaranteed if the contacts are synced or aggregated. 
You might want to try using [`LOOKUP_KEY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY) instead.